# How to draw line graph with JavaScript without using external libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, graph

To make it short:

I want to draw a line graph with JavaScript without using a (open-source) library. All I work with is JavaScript and jQuery (no-plugins!).

How can I manage this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use plugins? Google Charts is very powerfull tool

Comment: What browser compatibility do you need? Is SVG okay? Canvas? Either of these would make it fairly easy, but would be incompatible with older browsers. If you need full cross-browser compatibility, you'll want to use a library like Raphael for it, otherwise you're in for a world of hurt.

Comment: @Diode sure, canvas and svg will do

Comment: @SDC Chrome _or_ IE8/9 should support it

Comment: @keinabel - if you need IE8 support, then you can't use Canvas or SVG.

Comment: @SDC IE8 would be my fallback if there would have been no solution for Chrome or IE9 ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're overlooking [some very powerful libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632563/open-sourced-options-for-html5-chart-libraries), however if you're determined to do this yourself you're going to need to use HTML5 and the Canvas object.  Have a look [at this great tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20130407101311/http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/06/draw-a-line-graph-using-html5-canvas/) to get you started.  Here's a snapshot of what you'll need to get to grips with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var graph = $('#graph'),
        c = graph[0].getContext('2d');

    c.lineWidth = 2;
    c.strokeStyle = '#333';
    c.font = 'italic 8pt sans-serif';
    c.textAlign = "center";

    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(xPadding, 0);
    c.lineTo(xPadding, graph.height() - yPadding);
    c.lineTo(graph.width(), graph.height() - yPadding);
    c.stroke();
});
```

Comment: Canvas isn't supported by IE8, which the OP states he needs to support. However, he's accepted the answer, so one assumes he's happy with it.

Comment: @SDC very good point, and IE9 is only available on Windows 7.  The OP could use the explorercanvas which emulates the canvas' VML in older browsers (available at http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/)

Comment: well yes he could use that.... except that he's set against using any libraries. I agree with you that he really ought to consider using one, because he's not going to get anywhere without one.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution (besides external libraries) is probably the `canvas`, introduced in HTML5.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial) is a tutorial, and you can find much more information with Google.